# How to enhance the performance of the crossed-dyadic product of two large batched-arrays in Python (NumPy)?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication, tensor

I'd like to evaluate the minor- and major-symmetric crossed-dyadic product of two second order tensors in Python (NumPy).

```py
C[i,j,k,l] = (
    A[i, k] * B[j, l] + A[i, l] * B[k, j] + B[i, k] * A[j, l] + B[i, l] * A[k, j]
) / 4
```

I have two second-order tensors of shape `(3, 3, n)`, where the last trailing axis represents the batch dimension. I have implemented that function in my recently published Python package [hyperelastic](https://hyperelastic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hyperelastic/global/math.html#hyperelastic.math.cdya) and would like to get your feedback on how efficient my code is. I'd like to avoid any JIT-stuff like Numba.

Given two symmetric second-order tensors as NumPy-Arrays in reduced-Vector storage,

```py
import numpy as np

# any random 3x3 tensor
F = np.eye(3).reshape(3, 3, 1) + np.random.rand(3, 3, 100000) / 10

# a symmetric 3x3 tensor
C = F.T @ F

# Voigt-notation vector storage 
# (upper triangle items but sorted on the diagonals; starting from the main diag.)
i = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0]
j = [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2]
A = C[i, j]
```

my current implementation looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np

def cdya(A, B):
    i, j = [a.ravel() for a in np.indices((6, 6))]

    a = np.array([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2)])
    b = np.array([0, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4, 5, 4, 2]).reshape(3, 3)

    i, j, k, l = np.hstack([a[i], a[j]]).T

    ik = b[i, k].reshape(6, 6)
    jl = b[j, l].reshape(6, 6)

    il = b[i, l].reshape(6, 6)
    kj = b[k, j].reshape(6, 6)

    C = (A[ik] * B[jl] + A[il] * B[kj]) / 2

    if A is not B:
        C += (B[ik] * A[jl] + B[il] * A[kj]) / 2
        C /= 2

    return C


A = np.random.rand(6, 100000)
B = np.random.rand(6, 100000)

C = cdya(A, B)
```

On my machine this function takes approx. 100ms. An equivalent implementation with `np.einsum` in full tensor storage takes approx. 160ms.

```py
A = np.random.rand(3, 3, 100000)
B = np.random.rand(3, 3, 100000)

C = (
    np.einsum("ij...,kl...->ikjl...", A, B) + np.einsum("ij...,kl...->ilkj...", A, B) +
    np.einsum("ij...,kl...->ikjl...", B, A) + np.einsum("ij...,kl...->ilkj...", B, A)
) / 4
```

Do you see any room for improvements or have I already reached a quite good solution?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds more like a a CodeReview question

Comment: Maybe, but the answer I got was more or less the thing I was looking for. So stackoverflow wasn't the badest choice ;-). But thank you for your hint, I'll consider this for my questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with Numpy is that many relatively-large temporary arrays are created by default (for sake of convenience). This is expensive. You can do **in-place operations** though this is quite cumbersome to do. Besides, you can also factorize the final multiplication regarding whether the condition is taken or not:

Here is an example:

```py
def cdya_opt(A, B):
    i, j = [a.ravel() for a in np.indices((6, 6))]

    a = np.array([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2)])
    b = np.array([0, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4, 5, 4, 2]).reshape(3, 3)

    i, j, k, l = np.hstack([a[i], a[j]]).T

    ik = b[i, k].reshape(6, 6)
    jl = b[j, l].reshape(6, 6)

    il = b[i, l].reshape(6, 6)
    kj = b[k, j].reshape(6, 6)

    x1, x2, x3, x4 = A[ik], B[jl], A[il], B[kj]
    np.multiply(x1, x2, out=x1)
    np.multiply(x3, x4, out=x3)
    np.add(x1, x3, out=x1)

    if A is not B:
        x5, x6, x7, x8 = B[ik], A[jl], B[il], A[kj]
        np.multiply(x5, x6, out=x5)
        np.multiply(x7, x8, out=x7)
        np.add(x5, x7, out=x5)
        np.add(x5, x1, out=x1)
        np.multiply(x1, 0.25, out=x1)
    else:
        np.multiply(x1, 0.5, out=x1)

    return x1
```

If using other packages like **`numexpr`** is fine to you, then you can write a faster implementation:

```py
import numexpr as ne

def cdya_opt2(A, B):
    i, j = [a.ravel() for a in np.indices((6, 6))]

    a = np.array([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2)])
    b = np.array([0, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4, 5, 4, 2]).reshape(3, 3)

    i, j, k, l = np.hstack([a[i], a[j]]).T

    ik = b[i, k].reshape(6, 6)
    jl = b[j, l].reshape(6, 6)

    il = b[i, l].reshape(6, 6)
    kj = b[k, j].reshape(6, 6)

    x1, x2, x3, x4 = A[ik], B[jl], A[il], B[kj]

    if A is not B:
        x5, x6, x7, x8 = B[ik], A[jl], B[il], A[kj]
        ne.evaluate('(x1 * x2 + x3 * x4 + x5 * x6 + x7 * x8) * 0.25', out=x1)
    else:
        ne.evaluate('(x1 * x2 + x3 * x4) * 0.5', out=x1)

    return x1
```

---

### Performance results

Here are results on my machine (i5-9600KF CPU, running on Windows, with Numpy 1.24.3):

```
cdya:       112.0 ms
cdya_opt:    70.7 ms
cdya_opt2:   59.1 ms  <-----
```

The last version is almost twice faster. Most of the time is spent in operations like `A[ik]` which are not very well optimized in Numpy. Using Cython (or Numba) is a good way to make this code even faster. Note that Cython is not a JIT as opposed to Numba.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, wasn't aware of that! For my package, I'd like to support Jupyter Lite and a quick test told me that numexpr isn't installable there. So your first solution could be my preferred choice here...

Comment: Of course I tried to solve the problem with Numba and I managed to get ~20ms. However, for small problems, the JIT-overhead is huge. Also, as I wrote in my question, this function is part of my hyperelastic package, which is some sort of an add-on to [FElupe](https://github.com/adtzlr/felupe), my Python FEA package. And I'd like to support as much platforms as possible there - especially all kinds of Jupyter instances (including Jupyter Lite). Again, many many thanks for pointing out the main issues of the code snippet!

Comment: For the JIT overhead, you can compile the function eagerly at startup time. If this is not fine, the best alternative is certainly Cython. It is used to speed up many packages including Numpy itself and Scipy! It is very well supported on many platforms. AFAIK, the only downsides is that the final code is not really pure Python anymore and the build is a bit more complicated though it should be automated anyway.

Answer (score 1):

My final solution is now a trade-off between readability and speed. Now I also utilize the symmetry of the result. The function takes ~40ms to complete, which is fantastic.

```py
def cdya_final(A, B):
    i, j = [a.ravel() for a in np.triu_indices(6)]

    a = np.array([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2)])
    b = np.array([0, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4, 5, 4, 2]).reshape(3, 3)

    i, j, k, l = np.hstack([a[i], a[j]]).T

    ik = b[i, k]
    jl = b[j, l]

    il = b[i, l]
    kj = b[k, j]
    
    ij = b[i, j]
    kl = b[k, l]
    
    C = np.zeros((6, *np.broadcast_shapes(A.shape, B.shape)))
    
    A, B = np.broadcast_arrays(A, B)
    Aik, Bjl, Ail, Bkj = A[ik], B[jl], A[il], B[kj]
    
    values = np.multiply(Aik, Bjl, out=Aik) + np.multiply(Ail, Bkj, out=Ail)

    if A is not B:
        Bik, Ajl, Bil, Akj = B[ik], A[jl], B[il], A[kj]
        
        values += np.multiply(Bik, Ajl, out=Bik) + np.multiply(Bil, Akj, out=Bil)
        values /= 4
    else:
        values /= 2
    
    C[ij, kl] = C[kl, ij] = values

    return C
```

Thank you for your help!